# ReactJS:Google Map (Giving Invalid Value Error)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-maps

I currently working on [my reference (ReactJS Google Map)](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/). and I made this project in ReactJS and laravel.

I don't understand why tomchentw API Json Data is working on my google map, however my own API Json Data giving me error

> Hc {message: "not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Hc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…stanc
>
> InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in
>   property lat: not a number

**tomchentw: API DATA** https://gist.githubusercontent.com/farrrr/dfda7dd7fccfec5474d3/raw/758852bbc1979f6c4522ab4e92d1c92cba8fb0dc/data.json

**my own : API DATA**
[image: sample image]

My Codes:

```
{props.markers.map(marker => (

    <Marker
      key={marker.id}
      position={{ lat: marker.store_lat, lng: marker.store_long }}
    />
  ))}



 componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('/api/googlemapstore')
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
              markers: response.data
          })
        })

    }
```

Tomchentw Codes:

```
{props.markers.map(marker => (

    <Marker
      key={marker.photo_id}
      position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
    />
  ))}


 fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/farrrr/dfda7dd7fccfec5474d3/raw/758852bbc1979f6c4522ab4e92d1c92cba8fb0dc/data.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ markers: data.photos });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the values in your data are strings, not numbers.

You have:

```
'store_lat': '53.628301'
```

Should be:

```
'store_lat': 53.628301
```